# In SQL how do I find the difference in 2 lists by comparing 2 different rows?

Tags: sql, database

Here is my dilemma I have two lists list one is called student and list 2 is final_GPA. The listes look like this

*Student*
STUDENT_NAME
GPA_YEAR
AWARDS
SPORTS

*FINAL_GPA*
STUDENT_NAME
GPA_YEAR
FINAL_GRADES
GRADUATION

I need it to find all the students who don't yet have there final grades. The problem is the students are in the FINAL_GPA list already from previous years so I can't just check which STUDENT_NAME is not in both lists.

How can I find the STUDENT_NAME and GPA_YEAR of students who I haven't entered the FINAL_GRADES for yet?

Answer (score 1):

This is a case for NOT EXISTS:

```
select student_name, gpa_year
from student s 
where not exists (
    select 1
    from final_gpa f 
    where f.student_name = s.student_name
    and f.gpa_year = s.gpa_year
)
```